# UpdateMany items in array using field from current element

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I am trying to update one field in an array within all documents in the collection that match some array filter with a value of another field.

My Object structure looks like the following

```
Class School
{
   string Name;
   List<Professor> Professors;
}

Class Professor
{
   string Name;
   List<Course> Courses;
}

Class Course
{
   string Name;
   string CourseNumber
   DateTime StartDate;
   DateTime EndDate;
}
```

I want to update all the Course EndDates to their respective StartDate if they mach the array filter criteria (Course Number).

```
db.schools.updateMany(
  {},
  {$set: {"Professors.$[].Courses.$[c].EndDate": "Professors.$[].Courses.$[c].StartDate" }},
  {arrayFilters:[{"c.CourseNumber":{$eq:"ECON101"}}]}
  )
```

Currently it is setting the EndDates to the literal string of "Professors.$[].Courses.$[c].StartDate" and I cant figure out how to get the set to evaluate any expression.  (but it is selecting the correct objects to update

Ive tried simple things like trying to do a concat to create some new field.

```
db.schools.updateMany(
  {},
  {$set: {"Professors.$[].Courses.$[c].SomeString": {$concat:["a","b"]} }},
  {arrayFilters:[{"c.CourseNumber":{$eq:"ECON101"}}]}
  )
```

But I always get some message like

> The dollar ($) prefixed field '$concat' in 'Professors.0.Courses.0.SomeString.$concat' is not valid for storage

Is this an impossible thing I am trying to do? Or should I be using something other than update many?

Comment: To update a field with a value of another field, you need to use [Updates with Aggregation Pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/).

Comment: @prasad_ Yeah i know that ive been trying to figure out how to. When i use an aggregation method like concat i get the error: The dollar ($) prefixed field '$concat' in 'Professors.0.Courses.0.SomeString.$concat' is not valid for storage. Any suggestions on how i would use the aggregation pipeline for that simple example?

Comment: I think you can to lookup some examples in the earlier provided link - the syntax you are trying is _not correct_ for the  Updates with Aggregation Pipeline.